# Laravel 4 redirect with flash into Twig template

Tags: flash, redirect, laravel, laravel-4, twig

How do I - using Laravel 4 with TwigBridge (0.4.x) trying to redirect to a URL with flash data - access the value in Twig template please?

This is my code in the controller:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $profile = DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->update(array(
            'email'      => Input::get('email'),
            'title_id'   => Input::get('title_id'),
            'first_name' => Input::get('first_name'),
            'last_name'  => Input::get('last_name')
        )
    );

    return Redirect::to('/profile')
        ->with('message', array(
            'class' => 'success',
            'content' => 'Profile successfully updated.'
        )
    );
}
```

and this is my view:

```
{% extends 'base' %}

{% block title %}Profile :: {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Profile</h1>
</div>
{{ dump() }}

{% if flash %}
<div class="{{ flash.class }}">
    <a href="#close" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    {{ flash.message }}
</div>
{% endif %}

etc...
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, having dug around GitHub and other Laravel 4 repos available to me I found this solution:

```
{% if session_get('message') %}
<div class="alert alert-{{ session_get('message.class') }}">
    <a href="#close" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    {{ session_get('message.content') }}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Thanks for looking, hope it helps anyone!